# How to find the time of a row updated into a table in Sql Server 2005?

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2005, sql-delete, insert-update

Is it possible to find the time when the row was updated into a table. For Example

```
  ID            NAME               COURSE                   
 ----          ------             --------
  1            SACHIN              B.TECH
  2            AJITH               B.E
  3            ASIN                M.TECH
```

I want to find at which time, I updated the 2nd row of a table. Not only for Updating, but also during Insertion and Deletion. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you run a trace when the changes happen it is not possible.

Comment: My SQL is rusty, but isn't there something in the transaction logs?

Comment: You can query the transaction log with `DBCC LOG ('dbname')` but this is not reliable as the transaction log is truncated on backup.

Comment: OK, but I guess if the tracing was not enabled, that's the only hope left.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL Profiler

Microsoft SQL Server Profiler is a graphical user interface to SQL Trace for monitoring an instance of the Database Engine or Analysis Services. You can capture and save data about each event to a file or table to analyze later. For example, you can monitor a production environment to see which stored procedures are affecting performance by executing too slowly.

[SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx)

[Using SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx)